# How to paste into selected folder using "Path Finder" on Mac?

Tags: macos, pathfinder

Using the Mac app, *Path Finder*, how can I paste a file into a folder I've selected with my keyboard? By "selected", I mean it gets highlighted with a blue background.

I'm looking to do this without first navigating to that folder. The point with this procedure is to save time because I move a lot of files between folders.

*Path Finder*'s current behavior is to paste files into the currently opened folder. See below:
[image]

Comment: Googlers: I have created a thread at path finder support thread, you can also +1 the request there: http://support.cocoatech.com/discussions/problems/39802-how-to-paste-into-selected-folder